# updating Adobe Acrobat Reader DC using chololatey

Tags: chocolatey, choco

"Error upgrading application Adobe Acrobat Reader DC - \nWARNING: Generic MSI Error. This is a local environment error, not an issue with a package or the MSI itself - it could mean a pending reboot is necessary prior to install or something else

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned over on the [issue that was raised](https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/issues/2796), this isn't a Chocolatey CLI issue. It's an MSI installer issue.

My advice is read the error message first and follow its advice. If that doesn't work, do an internet search for that error code and follow standard troubleshooting for it.